# Cannot retrieve records from a Shared Data Extension using the SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

i tried  with the follwing Saop request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis- 
     open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
       <wsse:UsernameToken>
       <wsse:Username>test123@gmail.com</wsse:Username>
          <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
        200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">****** 
       </wsse:Password>
       </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
         <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
          <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtensionObject[Test DE]</ObjectType>

                <QueryAllAccounts>true</QueryAllAccounts>

      <Properties>Email</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
   </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
     </soapenv:Envelope>

       I always get the following response


      <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
       xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
         xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401- 
        wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis- 
       open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>RetrieveResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a5cc51af-790e-4876-8e35- 
     b47c09a06dce</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:123ad64f-08cf-46c6-bc9e- 
    21677d3ef3cc</wsa:RelatesTo>


          <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-81bacc7d-fc78-4a1d-8b72- 
         5d1d8120240e">
        <wsu:Created>2018-03-30T07:58:23Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2018-03-30T08:03:23Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         </wsse:Security>
      </soap:Header>
      <soap:Body>
        <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <OverallStatus>Error: Invalid object name 'C100010308.Test DE'. 
        </OverallStatus>
        <RequestID>80902d85-ee8d-4b82-9c97-ddfdfb04881d</RequestID>
        </RetrieveResponseMsg>
       </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is 'Test DE' the DataExtension name or is it the ExternalKey/CustomerKey?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this status despite my best efforts.

Comment: @mike Test DE is Data Extension Name i tried with External key also didn't work

Comment: Did it work for you? I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `ClientID` tag of the WSDL equal to the parent MID in order to access the shared Data Extension.

E.g. `<ClientID> MID_Of_Parent_BU</ClientID>`